# How do I extract .cpk files in Ubuntu?

Tags: software-recommendation, extract, tools

I have a .cpk file that needs to be extracted. So I tried to extract it in windows. But there are some illegal characters in that CPK file, so I couldn't open it. So, I tried to do it in Ubuntu. So, I downloaded `CPKtools` by kamikat.

Kamikat tool - https://github.com/kamikat/cpktools

But it didn't work as I intended. Maybe because it is outdated.

**WHAT IS CPK FILE?**

> Game package file used by games created with the CRI Middleware packaging software; can store graphics, audio, and other game data; used as a container for game files.
>
> CRI Middleware technology is used to package data for various game console systems, including those from Microsoft, Nintendo, Sega, and Sony.
>
> Pro Evolution Soccer and Dragon Ball Z games use this file format.

**WHAT IS CPK TOOLS?**

> CPK tools like CriPakTools, YACpkTools, CPK Unpack & Repack tools etc. extracts .cpk files and also compresses into .cpk files.

Comment: What's a "cpk file"? What created it? What does "extracted" mean in this case? How did you intend for it to work? How did it work? How can I tell if I can help?

Comment: @waltinator see this - https://fileinfo.com/extension/cpk

Comment: Welcome here! And please edit the question to explain what a cpk file is! We want to make the questions useful for other people too, not just for you. Also summarize what CPKtools is - maybe it is renamed or outdated when someone reads your question in 10 years. Oh, and we do not know what you intended, and where it went wrong! The cpk file format seems interesting - so it may be read still in 15 years. Rewrite it for that. Thanks for asking it!

Comment: I do not think it is unclear what is asked for. And it is even interesting. The question is of course not written in the way we need. I explained that to Prince in a previous comment.  Let's see for his edits!

Comment: @VolkerSiegel I agree with both waltinator that the question is unclear in its present form and with you that it's interesting and should be edited and eventually left open, so I voted to close it as unclear for now, but if you personal message me I will vote to reopen it if it is edited to make it less unclear.

Comment: @VolkerSiegel I clarified more. Is it helpful?
Please let me know.

Thank you.

Comment: @karel Sorry for not clearing things up. To be honest, I do not also know about cpk much, I just play the game, and If someone makes an update for the game, I just download it and extract it then I put those files in my existing cpk. But this time some problems appeared. There are some illegal characters in that file.  So no software in windows couldn't extract. 
So I tried to use kamikat's tool in Ubuntu. It didn't work. It crashes, maybe because it's a very old tool and not updated.

Sorry again and thank you.

Comment: The last edit made the question clear enough, and the question has been reopened.

Comment: @Prince «But it didn't work as I intended.» Which error did it gave you? This one? https://github.com/kamikat/cpktools/issues/3